# why i am not getting the output for the required program?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

In this program, I m creating an object and then just destroying the object using destructor..and I'm using a static variable as a counter...the program compiles successfully but I m not getting any output...and when I try to run it on code block I get a message "code blocks stopped working"..I m at windows 10 with gnu GCC compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class ashish
{
int *age;
public:
static int classm;
ashish()
{
    *age=10;
    classm++;
}
~ashish(){
cout<<"this going to destroy the object";
delete age;}
};
int ashish::classm=0;
int main()
{
ashish *blast;
blast=new ashish();
cout<<ashish::classm<<"chec"<<endl;
delete blast;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you're not indenting your code.

Comment: Because you are using dynamic memory when you don't need to.

Comment: What happens when you step through the code with a debugger?

Answer (score 3):

You're not allocating memory for `age`, like you did with `blast` (`blast = new ashish();`)

Comment: after changing *age=10; to age=new int a=90 in m getting an error like this:                                                                                                              In constructor 'ashish::ashish()':                                                                                     error: expected ';' before 'a'

Comment: @AshishRanjan you have to add a `;` after the `int` and before the `a`.